# Command to run multiple test scripts, collating the exit codes into a final pass/fail?

Tags: node.js, shell, testing

I have a single command to run all my projects tests, something like this:

```
$ node test/test1.js && node test/test2.js && node test/test3.js
```

But the problem is, if the first test script has failed tests (and therefore ends with a non-zero exit code), the other two test scripts won't run. Ideally I'd like to see the console output for all three test scripts, even if the first one failed.

What I want is a way to run **all** my test scripts, in series, even if some of them fail... But if **any** of them failed, then the **final** exit code should be 1.

Is there any command syntax that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this requires some shell programming that doesn't read well in a single line. I'd create `./bin/test.sh` script and call that from your package.json script section. Here's the gist of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."
fails=""
check() {
  if [[ $1 -ne 0]]; then
    fails="${fails} $2"
  fi 
}

# explicit list here but a for loop would also work
node ./test/test1.js
check $? test1

node ./test/test2.js
check $? test2

if [[ -n "${fails}" ]]; then
  echo "Tests failed: ${fails}"
  exit 1
fi
```